# Error in reading file java.io

Tags: java, java-io, fileinputstream

So i'm trying to read the following string from the text file addToLibrary.txt

```
 file:/Users/JEAcomputer/Music/iTunes/iTunes%20Media/Music/Flight%20Of%20The%20Conchords/Flight%20Of%20The%20Conchords/06%20Mutha'uckas.mp3
```

But when I do i get the following error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/Users/JEAcomputer/Music/iTunes/iTunes%20Media/Music/Flight%20Of%20The%20Conchords/Flight%20Of%20The%20Conchords/06%20Mutha'uckas.mp3 (No such file or directory)
```

Whats odd is that I got that string from a fileChooser using this method:

```
public static void addToLibrary(File f) {

    String fileName = "addToLibrary.txt";

    try {
        FileWriter filewriter = new FileWriter(fileName, true);
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(filewriter);
        bufferedWriter.newLine();
        bufferedWriter.write(f.toURI().toString());
        System.out.println("Your file has been written");
        bufferedWriter.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(
            "Error writing to file '"
            + fileName + "'");
    } finally {
    }
}
```

An even stranger error is that my file reader can read things in another folder but not anything in iTunes Media.
I attempt to read all the files in the different folders with the following method:

```
public void getMusicDirectory() {
    int index = 0;
    try {


        File[] contents = musicDir.listFiles();
        //System.out.println(contents[3].toString());
        for (int i = 0; i < contents.length; i++) {
            //System.out.println("----------------------------------------"+contents.length);
            String name = contents[i].getName();
            //System.out.println(name);

            if (name.indexOf(".mp3") == -1) {
                continue;
            }

            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(contents[i]);
            file.read();
            System.out.println(contents[i].toURI().toString());
            songsDir.add(new Song((new MediaPlayer(new Media(contents[i].toURI().toString()))), contents[i]));
            file.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error -- " + e.toString());
    }
    try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("addToLibrary.txt"))) {

        //System.out.println("In check login try");
        for (String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null; ) {
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(line));
            file.read();
            songsDir.add(new Song(new MediaPlayer(new Media(line)), new File(line)));
            file.close();
        }
        // line is not visible here.
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error reading add to library-- " + e.toString());
    }


}
```

So how can i make this work? why does the first part of the method work but not the second?

Comment: That's a URL, you'd need to use a java.net.URL and the read from its InputStream

Comment: So in code what do you suggest sorry thats a bit vague

Comment: Take a look at [java.net.URL#openStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openStream()), this returns InputStream

Comment: But if anything I'm using a URI not a URL?

Comment: Then use URI's toURL method...

Comment: I just tried this and it still isn't working, can you write in code what you think would work rather than just saying it or linking me?

Comment: A URL is not a file. Ergo, you can't open one using FileInputStream. Have you considered using file paths instead of URLs?

Comment: Re URI/URL, URLs are a type of URIs, like if URL was a subclass of URI. (This is about URLs and URIs in general, not the `URL` and `URI` Java classes). The string you wrote to addToLibrary.txt is both a URI and a URL.

Comment: Well whats weird is that I can use the URI's in the first part of getMusicDirectory() but not the second. The second part is basically the same thing but its not working

Comment: @dafly45 That's because the first part is using Files, not URIs/URLs. Unless you have a good reason, you probably *don't* want to convert your File to a URI or URL.

Comment: @immibis ah that makes sense! thanks, so how do you propose in code i solve my issue?

Comment: @dafly45 Before I answer anything else, can I ask why you're opening a FileInputStream, reading one byte and then closing it again for each file?

Comment: @immibis well i use addToLibrary.txt to keep track of where files added are rather than moving them. I use fileinputstream because thats just the way I learned how

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69054/discussion-between-immibis-and-dafly45).

Answer (score 1):

You are not having a problem reading the string

```
file:/Users/JEAcomputer/Music/iTunes/iTunes%20Media/Music/Flight%20Of%20The%20Conchords/Flight%20Of%20The%20Conchords/06%20Mutha'uckas.mp3
```

from a file. That part works fine. Your problem is after that, when you try to open the file with the path:

```
file:/Users/JEAcomputer/Music/iTunes/iTunes%20Media/Music/Flight%20Of%20The%20Conchords/Flight%20Of%20The%20Conchords/06%20Mutha'uckas.mp3
```

because that's not actually a path; it's a URI (although it can be converted to a path).

You *could* convert this to a path, in order to open it, but you have no reason to - your code doesn't actually read from the file (apart from the first byte, which it does nothing with) so there's no point in opening it.  Delete the following lines:

```
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(contents[i]); // THIS ONE
file.read(); // THIS ONE
System.out.println(contents[i].toURI().toString());
songsDir.add(new Song((new MediaPlayer(new Media(contents[i].toURI().toString()))), contents[i]));
file.close(); // THIS ONE
```

and

```
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(line)); // THIS ONE
file.read(); // THIS ONE
songsDir.add(new Song(new MediaPlayer(new Media(line)), new File(line)));
file.close(); // THIS ONE
```

Comment: So that worked for part of the issue but just another one popped up:
  
    error IO! java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/Users/JEAcomputer/Music/iTunes/iTunes%20Media/Music/James%20Taylor/Greatest%20Hits/02%20Carolina%20In%20My%20Mind.mp3 (No such file or directory)
Error reading add to library-- java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: @dafly45 On which line?

Comment: I would suggest that the problems are related to `bufferedWriter.write(f.toURI().toString());` and `songsDir.add(new Song((new MediaPlayer(new Media(contents[i].toURI().toString()))), contents[i]));` and `FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(line));` which are trying to read or store the `File` `URI` as a `String`...just saying...

Answer (score 0):

`file:/Users/JEAcomputer/Music/iTunes/iTunes%20Media/Music/Flight%20Of%20The%20Conchords/Flight%20Of%20The%20Conchords/06%20Mutha'uckas.mp3` is not a valid `File` reference, especially under Windows.

Since you've idendtified the `String` as a URI, you should treat it as such...

```
URI uri = URI.create("file:/Users/JEAcomputer/Music/iTunes/iTunes%20Media/Music/Flight%20Of%20The%20Conchords/Flight%20Of%20The%20Conchords/06%20Mutha'uckas.mp3");
```

Okay, but, there's no real way to read `URI`, but you can read a `URL`, so we need to convert the `URI` to `URL`, luckily, this is quite simple...

```
URL url = uri.toURL();
```

From there you can use `URL#openStream` to open an `InputStream` (which you can wrap in a `InputStreamReader`) and read the contents of the file, for example...

```
String imageFile = "file:/...";
URI uri = URI.create(imageFile);
try {
    URL url = uri.toURL();
    try (InputStream is = url.openStream()) {

        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024 * 4];
        int bytesRead = -1;
        int totalBytesRead = 0;
        while ((bytesRead = is.read(bytes)) != -1) {

            // Somthing, something, something, bytes
            totalBytesRead += bytesRead;

        }

        System.out.println("Read a total of " + totalBytesRead);

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
} catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

You could, however, save your self a lot of issues and stop using things like `f.toURI().toString());` (`File#toURI#toString`) and simply use `File#getPath` instead...This would allow you to simply create a new `File` reference from the `String`...

Also, your resource management needs some work, basically, if you open it, you should close it.  See [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) for some more ideas